# QCoreApplication::exec error when running MatPlotLib plot in pyqt5 gui

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have a pyqt5 QtDesigner MainWindow and utterly failed to get a matplotlib plot to include the NavigationToolbar in a plot widget, despite following various examples using:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('QT5Agg')
from matplotlib.backends.qt_compat import QtCore, QtWidgets, is_pyqt5
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvas, NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
```

I don't want to go there again!

But if I simply use plt.plot() it pops up a lovely graph in a new window with the toolbar etc Great. However, the Shell makes a complaint:

> QCoreApplication::exec: The event loop is already running

I understand why (or I think I do) and why you should use the shenanigans above, but nothing happens, the GUI does not hang, nothing crashes.  Should I be worried or can I just ignore it?

Comment: I don't understand. What is the problem? Having "all" those imports?

Comment: Err no - it’s the QCoreApplication::exec appearing at the command line or in the shell

Comment: It's not clear how you "utterly failed to get a matplotlib plot to include the NavigationToolbar", but, in both cases, we need a [mre].

Comment: I could not get the code right, in any case it was better to have the graph appear in a new window so I am happy with that.  Secondly there is no point in providing code, it is simply if you 'do' a plt.show() from inside a pyqt5 MainWindow() you get the exec message as above.  I am just looking to see if I need to worry about this because I am not seeing any consequences as yet?

Comment: The MRE is required as basic `plt.show()` does *not* cause that warning: matplotlib should be able to detect an existing QApplication and use its event loop (or start it). That warning is shown whenever something tries to start the event loop while it's already running, and AFAIK matplotlib shouldn't do it in normal conditions.